# Although it's colors are somewhat celestial

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Half comes from a battery, half comes from a mollusc.

Split it asymmetrically and it does what you would expect burning brimstone to do!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But the riddle is tagged "wordplay", maybe this helps?

Comment: I mean are you saying half: comes from a battery or half comes from: a battery.

Comment: I am not sure if you want it to be ambiguous, if so then that is fine, I was just wondering if you did not and accidentally made it so.

Comment: Let's assume it was intentional, otherwise it may be to easy. I hope it will be clear once somebody gets their mind on the right track. If it proves too difficult, I will rephrase the question slightly to take the ambiguity out

Comment: If it was you might be in danger of multiple legitimate answers.

Comment: Why not submit a guess to show how ambiguous the question really is? "False correct" answers may be entertaining in their own right... (Also I'd like to add a disclaimer: This IS my first posted riddle here, and I am not an English native speaker, so it may well be that I lack the experience necessary to find a perfectly watertight wording!)

Comment: If no-one has the answer after say a day, you can post a hint in hidden 'spoiler' style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)

Half comes from a battery,

> Power

half comes from a mollusc.

> Shell

Split it asymmetrically and it does what you would expect burning brimstone to do!

> Powers Hell

Title

> The standard dark blue background pocked with white does look somewhat celestial.

Comment: Correct! Congratulations :-)